# PhpStorm how to detect/highlight closing "tag" in PHP's alternate syntax of contol structures

Tags: php, phpstorm

Pretty much what the title says. Is there a way to make PhpStorm highlight the closing "tag" when using PHP's alternate syntax for control structures?

Take a look at this sample code for example:

```
<?
if($x==5) {
    echo "x is equal to 5";
}
?>
```

If i put the cursor next to or before the opening/closing brace, PhpStorm will automatically highlight the matching opening/closing brace.

Now, if we write the same code but this time using PHP's alternate syntax for control structures, we end up with something like this:

```
<? if ($x==5): ?>
x is equal to 5
<? endif; ?>
```

In this case, PhpStorm will not highlight either the opening "if" or the closing "endif;". Is there a way to make it highlight it?

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, this is now supported in 2017.1 EAP. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14517

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately current versions of PhpStorm cannot do that.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14517 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to be notified on any progress. So far it has not been associated with any specific future version (not currently planned for implementation).

Related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-566

Comment: I can't believe it is still not supported in PhpStorm after all those years! It's a fundamental syntax which I use constantly when writing template. Why is it that I ALWAYS see issues like this. A problem that is really annoying for everybody, and the developer's just neglect it like nothing is even wrong. I see this behaviour exhibited everywhere, quite frustrating.

Comment: @thephpdev Well .. this is not a bug but missing functionality.. hence the priority is lower. It has quite few votes though (32 at the moment) .. but devs still do not think that this is an important issue (and in *certain* sense they are right .. just with that many votes (compared to most of other tickets) they should have given much more attention for this one). It will have much better effect if you ask/complain devs in the actual ticket -- doing it here will not do much (OK -- I'm as the author of this answer will see it .. but what about actual target individuals -- JB devs?)

Comment: Of course not body from JerBrains will see it. I posted the comment on stack overflow. I am going to add my comment on the ticket, too. I have every intention of doing that - worry not. Also, this "feature" is not so much a "feature" that Is optional in my eyes. It's basic PHP syntax, and for an IDE to not support that is the kind of thing I'd expect to see on a lightweight code editor.

Answer (score 2):

The 2017 version of PHPStorm now supports it. But apparently they are having issues with it that they turned off this feature, they did not mention what the issue is though. But you can still enable it by going to:  *Find Action->Registry->php.brace.alt.syntax*

See response here [Alternate PHP syntax](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14517#id_l.I.ic.it.c.c_27_2063422.comment_content_row_27_2063422)

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex search and step through, counting the start and ends of the nested conditionals.

```
(if\s*\(.+\).*:)|(endif)
```